# When pushlishing MVC project to server, bootstrap.css edits don't migrate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC project that I built in Visual Studio 2013 and when I publish the project up to Windows Server 2012, any changes I made in the bootstrap.css file don't migrate. I know it is just that file specifically because any changes I made to the Site.css file appear on the server. Everything else works except the one bootstrap.css file.

I really don't want to have to pull out the changes in bootstrap.css, it would take a lot of searching. Is this problem common? Has anyone even heard about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea to take the code from my bootstrap.css file and minify it manually, then copy it into the boostrap.min.css file. After doing that, I published the project back up to my server and everything is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio's Properties pane (for the file in question) check that the `Copy To Output Directory` property is set to `Copy Always`.

Also, in the Publish settings dialog, on the **Settings** tab,
expand the **File Publish Options** collapsible region and make sure *Remove additional files at destination* is checked (turned on).

Comment: I'll try this and see what happens.